# in Intellij I cannot dock project window

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I want like this

[image]

But mine is like this. It's showing as another window

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before unchecking window mode, select the window you want to dock

Answer (score 5):

You should uncheck floating mode:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on little settings wheel and uncheck windowed mode.